# How do I reference cells from another sheet and order them in the current one?

Tags: excel, google-sheets

So I have some columns with 2 rows, containing Name and a number.

[image]

How do I link this data in another sheet (or even current sheet) and also have them ordered by that number?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use VLOOKUP function.

> Use VLOOKUP, one of the lookup and reference functions, when you need
>   to find things in a table or a range by row. For example, look up an
>   employee's last name by her employee number, or find her phone number
>   by looking up her last name (just like a telephone book).

In its common usage, Excel VLOOKUP searches through your lists of data based on the unique identifier and brings you a piece of information associated with that unique identifier.

In practice, VLOOKUP formulas are rarely used to find data in the same worksheet. Most often you will have to look up and pull the matching data from a different sheet.

[Microsoft Tutorial On This](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Excel Workbook Exampls]

Cell references below refer to the worksheet shown.

1 - transpose your data by selecting cells A4:B8, entering

```
=TRANSPOSE(A1:E2)
```

into the formula bar, then pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to create an array formula.

2 - Sort the numerical data using the LARGE() function in cells B10:B14

```
=LARGE($B$4:$B$8,C10)
```

The 1-5 in C10:C14 are used to select the 1st largest, 2nd largest, etc.
This is not an array formula. Enter it in B10, then copy it down.

3 - Find the name that corresponds with the number using INDEX and MATCH

```
=INDEX($A$4:$A$8,MATCH(B10,$B$4:$B$8,0))
```

Again, not an array formula. Enter in A10 and copy down.

These steps can be combined somewhat, I left them separate for clarity.

This method doesn't handle duplicate numbers.

Comment: Why Step 1?  Just do horizontal lookups. INDEX can do that.

Comment: also FWIW, if you replace the C10 reference in the Large with `Row(1:1)` you do not need the helper column.  `=LARGE($B$4:$B$8,Row(1:1))` as it is copied down the row will increase as will the integer that is returned.